# Как скомпилировать Python TKinter программу в .apk файл для Android?

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, tkinter, apk

Решил попробовать сделать простое приложение для опыта под Android на Python с помощью TKinter. Возможно ли это сделать? Я слышал можно как-то через средство Kivy это сделать. И будут ли какие-то проблемы? На пример разрешение 1080x1920 будет в коде, но как это будет отображаться на мобильных устройствах? Опишите пожалуйста все методы компиляции в .apk и все нюансы которые могут произойти

Comment: Питон для андроида? Ар ю крэйзи? (если вы про киви с бильдозером, так это х...-рень)

Comment: Java, kotlin, c#, c++.

Comment: *Опишите пожалуйста все методы компиляции в .apk и все нюансы которые могут произойти* - слишком широкий вопрос.

Comment: Я как то наткнулся на статью про сборку python скрипта в apk прямо в Android studio но не сохранил в закладках так что сложного там не чего нет Pydroid приложение как то ведь работает...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor почему киви это х... А как же kivymd, получается очень даже красивы прилаги

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin 1. Тормозит. Очень. 2. Не customizable: я могу написать прогу на PyQt5 и оформить ее так, как хочу. И виджеты могу всяие использовать и писать.  3. Типа можно собрать под андроид? Ну как бы можно, но на маках у меня не собиралось — а говорят можно. И запуситься ли это на андроиде (меньше чем за 10сек)? Ответы на эти вопросы зависят от вывода команды `print(randint(0, 4294967296))` (т.е. хрен знает). 4. `Ну и придется костылить / вносить правки в исходники kivy, если это что-то более-менее серьезное, документация там не на высшем уровне тоже.`

Comment: @VictorVosMottor так он вроде работает только на линукс, не? Да и вроде запуск только 1 долгий.э а потом запускается шустрее. А на счёт сборки в бульдозера это да, жесть

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Ну на линуксе то он запускается — у меня на убунте запустился. Но да это — жесть.

Comment: Если что-то не по нраву лично вам, это не значит, что это кусок говна)

Comment: @vp_arth Я лично этого не говорил — просто: если я "сожрал кактус" с каким-то фреймворком или еще чем-то, мне хочется предупредить людей, что возможно это будет просто трата время —  nothing else ;)

Comment: Исходя из ваших комментариев про то, что Tk не идет под Android (а я вам показал, что вы не правы), и всего того, что вы тут написали про Qt и Kivy, то я могу смело заявить, что вы просто - пустослов и рукожоп, который вообще не разбирается в том, о чем он пишет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, на kivy можно сделать, но будут проблемы. Главная из них - приложение не будет работать в фоновом режиме (свернул - оно закрылось). Ну и придется костылить/ вносить правки в исходники kivy, если это что-то более-менее серьезное, документация там не на высшем уровне тоже. Про tkinter забудьте если для android пишите.

Рекомендую к прочтению эту статью: https://habr.com/ru/post/348226/

Comment: Зачем вы вводите людей в заблуждение, если совершенно не знакомы с вопросом! Во-первых, `приложение не будет работать в фоновом режиме (свернул - оно закрылось)` - вы из какого годы пришли, Kivy приложение прекрасно работает в фоне. Во-вторых, `документация там не на высшем уровне` - У Kivy одна из самых крутых документаций в мире!  В третьих, `Про tkinter забудьте если для android пишите` - и здесь вы не правы, ибо Tkinter отлично работает на Android.

Comment: @Xyanight Да вы что? Может мне скиньте скрин tk под андроидом?

Comment: Пожалуйста - https://habrastorage.org/webt/k2/bf/sf/k2bfsf2cw1f_7pjvv3i1kcyeawk.png

Comment: Ну и еще - https://habrastorage.org/webt/zf/vc/k_/zfvck_fyqzaidpnmff82dudne5i.png